# Template function pointer array variable with deduced arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to use an array of function pointers without specifying the pointer type.
Declaring it works, but I cannot access the contents without passing the template arguments, which defeats the purpose. Is there a way to work around this? I am using C++17.

std::function works in this case, but I would like to avoid its usage.

```cpp
#include <functional>

bool f(int x);
bool g(int x);

static std::function<decltype(f)> fps[] {f, g};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr T (*fpsa[])(Args...) {f, g};

int main() {
    fps[0](1); // OK
    fpsa<bool,int>[0](1); // OK
    fpsa[0](1); // error: use of variable template 'fpsa' requires template arguments
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `std::array<decltype(f), 2> fpsa{f, g};`?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `std::function`? Any way of doing this would basically replicate what `std::function` is doing anyway. Are all functions supposed to be guaranteed to be callable with an `int` argument and return `bool`? If the signatures of all functions are *exactly* the same, see comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to use an array of function pointers without specifying the pointer type.

In this case, you can use class template argument deduction with `std::array`:

```
constexpr auto fpsa = std::array{f, g};
```

That should be enough. No need to make it a template variable.

Comment: This is also a solution, but I wonder whether there's a mechanism in the core language that would let us do this conveniently with the array type when the standard library implementation is unavailable (e.g. embedded software).

Comment: @5305cc92c0c29327213f2ef4990665 of course. You can easily implement `std::array` using the core langage only. Note that `std::array` is only a thin wrapper over a c-array, and don't allocate. I think it's officially in freestanding, so any recent distribution for your embedded system should ship it.